# How to get all selected values of multiselect dropdown in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, combobox

How to get all selected values of multi select dd in C#

Let's suppose I have a multi combo box and in which i have selected 3 values out of 5 values. So how could I fetch the selected Values only.

Answer (score 0):

A friendly question, is it really a combobox you are using? Most comboboxes/dropdownlists I have come across supports only single select.

Even stack overflow tag suggests the same:

[image]

Is it instead a listview or something similar, these controls often has SelectedIndices and/or SelectedItems. It also has boolean property "MultiSelect" to support single or multiselect.

[image]

Comment: Sorry ... It's my bad, actually it's a multi select drop down

Comment: @RishiSharma and it does not have any properties inline with "SelectedItems", "SelectedIndices", "Selected..."? 

What kind of control is? is it in Open Source library? Webform? Winform?